# Continuous optimization with a Euclidean TSP objective

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming, quadratic-programming, traveling-salesman, multi-objective-optimization

I am trying to solve a problem of the form $$\min_{x_1,\dots,x_n} f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$$ subject to a constraint that $\mathrm{length}(\mathrm{TSP}(x_1,\dots,x_n))\leq c$, where $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are all points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $f$ is a convex function, and $\mathrm{TSP}()$ denotes the shortest TSP tour through the points.  There are obvious ways to formulate this as an IP or a QIP by introducing a binary variable $y_{ij}$ representing the tour and doing the usual tricks (big $M$ for IP, and taking products $y_{ij}\|x_i-x_j\|$.

I am wondering if anyone has had any experience with problems of this sort, and if there are additional tricks that could improve performance?  A reference would help too as I don't know what to google to find similar results.

Comment: You may try to solve the problem as a black-box problem, using Concord or even a TSP heuristic to solve the TSP subproblem. It wouldn't be exact since the TSP constraint is certainly non-convex, but might be enough to find good solutions in reasonable time

Comment: That's a great idea!  Any recommendations for a decent black-box solver?

Comment: Either a derivative free solver such as Nomad, see https://doi.org/10.1007/s10898-021-01085-0 for other ones, or a derivative based solver such as Ipopt (open source) or Knitro (commercial)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the objective to optimize?

Comment: It's just $\sum_i \|x_i - p_i \|$, for given points $p_i$.  And in fact I'm not even married to this specific version, I'd be happy to reverse the objective and constraint, or even just take a weighted combintation of the two.

Comment: If $\sum_i \| x_i - p_i\|$ is small enough, the sequence of shortest TSP tour of $x_i$ should be the same as $p_i$. Then you can pre-calculate TSP(p), and replace length(TSP(x)) with the length of the fixed route of $x_i$.

Comment: Let me suggest you to verify if the cost function f satisfies the triangle inequality. If yes, then TSP is NP-complete.